# Why does the installer freeze at the moving dots?

Tags: installation, dell, live-cd

I plan to install Ubuntu as the sole operating system on my old Dell Latitude 110L and the install freezes at the Ubuntu starting dots - it doesn't even get to the point where it asks if you want Ubuntu as the sole operating system. I've tried different USB sticks, and now two different CDs. I even re-formatted the C drive on the old Dell and re-installed a fresh copy of Windows in case there was any interfering junk. Still can't get past the dots.

I've done this on other computers without a problem - any advice?

Comment: What are the specs of your Dell?

Comment: Add the `nomodeset` boot option and try again...

Comment: looked it up, looks like a 1.7 Ghz with 1.28Gig of ram (probably shared with graphics) so its an old one

Answer (score 1):

Your issue doesn't have anything to do with Windows XP.  Either the Ubuntu live CD doesn't get along with your hardware, or you have a corrupt CD.

Try using the Alternate install disk.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen, and it isn't even due to driver issues. My fix was to download an older version of Ubuntu and then do the distribution upgrade once it was installed.

Answer (score 0):

> I even re-formatted the C drive on the old Dell and re-installed a fresh copy of Windows

Did you try just formatting the disk, instead of reinstalling Windows? Try it again then.

Answer (score 0):

You can bear in mind that the earlier LTS release (10.04) is still supported. It may work for you better than 12.04. As Linus said, t's a VERY difficult thing to create an OS that works on absolutely EVERYTHING; look at the problems Micro$oft has with software that they released themselves not running on W7.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to install ubuntu over windows?
hmm... very strange.
Pending you have attempted to install via the live CD (usb)
which you have: Then i would would guess that you have 
1. a locked partition on your drive. (some vendors used to use locked recovery partitions)
2. Grub is not installing on the correct drive/correct way.
Any way I think of it, seems like a Hard drive partition issue.

Try This

Go into the live cd via "Try Ubuntu" option.
Open the program "gparted" 
Look on the device list for your hard drive (Something bigger than your USB sticks) and look post the details, or delete your problem. (if it doesnt make sense, I recommend asking or reading the gparted manual)